# Angular js 1.x custom directive - duplicate fields

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am wrapping the bootstrap-select(https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) jquery control into an angular js 1.x directive.

I will show first of all the code and markup then show you what is basically going wrong.

Template of the directive:

```
<select id="{{name}}"
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="selectedOption"
    ui-jq="selectpicker"
    ui-options='{ iconBase: "famfamfam-flag", tickIcon: "fa fa-check" }'>
<option ng-repeat="o in data" value="{{o.id}}">{{o.label}}</option>
```

Directive code:

```
(function () {
appModule.directive('yesNoDeclineCombo', ['$timeout', 
    function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: '/yesNoDeclineCombo.cshtml',
            scope: {
                selectedOption: '=?',
                name: '@'
            },
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
                $scope.data = app.consts.yesNoDeclineData;
                $scope.data.unshift({ id: null, label: 'Not Assigned' });

                //refresh combo
                $timeout(function () {
                    $(element).selectpicker('refresh');
                });

                $scope.$watch('selectedOption', function (newValue) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $(element).selectpicker('refresh');
                    }, 0);
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

})();

Markup use:

```
<yes-no-decline-combo selected-option="vm.specialDietId" ng-required="vm.isFieldRequired('SpecialDiet')" name="SpecialDiet"></yes-no-decline-combo>
```

Markup rendering:

```
<select id="SpecialDiet" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-isolate-scope ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ng-model="selectedOption" ui-jq="selectpicker" ui-options="{ iconBase: &quot;famfamfam-flag&quot;, tickIcon: &quot;fa fa-check&quot; }" selected-option="vm.specialDietId" ng-required="vm.isFieldRequired('SpecialDiet')" name="SpecialDiet" required="required" tabindex="-98">
<!-- ngRepeat: o in data --><option ng-repeat="o in data" value="" class="ng-binding ng-scope" selected="selected">Not assigned</option><!-- end ngRepeat: o in data --><option ng-repeat="o in data" value="1" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Yes</option><!-- end ngRepeat: o in data --><option ng-repeat="o in data" value="2" class="ng-binding ng-scope">No</option><!-- end ngRepeat: o in data --><option ng-repeat="o in data" value="3" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Decline To Answer</option><!-- end ngRepeat: o in data -->
```

Notice that the "name" attribute was only added on the directive in HTML and then got copied into the new directive markup. Also, you notice that all attributes added on the directive on HTML got copied into the rendered select control, like "ng-required" and "selected-option".

Why is this happening? Shouldn't only the directive template be rendered and bound to whatever data I feed in to the directive?

Thanks

Comment: Try to remove `replace: true,` from dir

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What would replace do in that case?